# c# - update ms-access database records with same id independently

Tags: c#, database, winforms, datatable

I have a relational ms-access database for some students. (database is filled already with some data)
there are two tables in my database:
1. tblStuInfo for student's general information.
2. tblStuEducation for managing their grades and interests **for each year**.

column named "**StuID**" is primary key in tblStuInfo  & foreign key 
in tblStuEducation.

[My database structure looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XO8c.jpg)
&
[example data looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HjCB.jpg)

in my form load event, dynamic textboxes are automatically created for each record in tblStuEducation table, and they are filled appropriately with no problem.

my problem is when i edit some information (here assume just EduYear) through winform and click save, all records will get same value (last textbox)

here is my save button code:

```
connection.Open();

OleDbCommand updateStuEducation = new OleDbCommand();
updateStuEducation.Connection = connection;
readStuEducation.CommandText = "select * from tblStuEducation where stuID = 1000";

//textBoxNamesArray use LINQ to save all values from textboxes with txtEduYear in their name
    string[] textBoxNamesArray = tabpEdu.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(a => a.Name.Contains("txtEduYear")).Select(a => a.Text).ToArray();
    Int32 i = 0;

    foreach (string value in textBoxNamesArray)
    {
        readStuEducation.CommandText = "update tblStuEducation set EduYear = '" + value[i] + "'";
        readStuEducation.ExecuteNonQuery();
        i++;
    }

    connection.Close();
```

i need following:

```
if i = 0 => value[0] Save in Row[0] of tblStuEducation where stuID = 1000. 
if i = 1 => value[1] Save in Row[1] of tblStuEducation where stuID = 1000. 
if i = 2 => value[2] Save in Row[2] of tblStuEducation where stuID = 1000.
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd make three changes;

1) you need a WHERE clause -- 'update tblStuEducation set EduYear = x' will update EduYear on every record in the table.

2) You've got a SQL injection vulnerability here; concatenating strings to make a CommandText isn't acceptable. You'll need to call [readStuEducation.Parameters.Add()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection(v=vs.110).aspx) or something similar. (read [this about parameters for OleDb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx))

3) It looks like there may be some confusion when you're accessing `value[i]`; since `value` already contains the value in the appropriate textbox. value[i] will return a single character from that string.

So you should get something like

```
readStuEducation.CommandText = "update tblStuEducation set Grade = ? where stuID = ? and EduYear = ?";
readStuEducation.AddParameter(value); // value to set
readStuEducation.AddParameter(1000); // student ID
readStuEducation.AddParameter(eduYear); // student ID
readStuEducation.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: thank you steve. but it still update all EduYear column in records where stuID = 1000 with the latest textbox value. i need to update each row with it's independent year value.

Comment: Then you may need another condition in the WHERE clause -- I've added one as an example; this would set the grade for a particular student for a particular year.

Comment: that's exactly my problem. except stuID, all other columns can have different values so conditions may vary. i am looking for a solution to navigate through each row in update query. like when we use DataReader while loop

Comment: Dear Steve. i could solve it by adding a new column (counter) in my second table  and add another condition for it in the WHERE clause as u suggested. Just want to say thank you.